# How to define Eclipse classpath variables in IntelliJ

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

In Eclipse, classpath variables can be set at this link: Window > Preferences > Java > Build Path > Classpath Variables.

Now I imported my Eclipse project on IntelliJ. How to set my classpath variables like I did in Eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IntelliJ, Eclipse classpath variables are called path variables and they are accessible via this link: File > Settings > Appearance & Behaviour > Path Variables.

Comment: Thanks, that you shared this.